# datepicker select date from debug console

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, datepicker, click

I'm trying detect which kind of event is used by `datepicker` when I'm choosing date by clicking on them.

The code below works on chrome but does not work on firefox i cannot understand why.

Also, I found a second type of `datepicker` and it does not react when I choose dates from `click` event manually. However the structure is the same as `datepicker` it gives chosen value by clicking.

My question is if something which is triggered by mouse click must be triggered from `jQuery` click event too? And if yes, why in my case (I mean second `datepicker`) is not triggered from click event? why click event does not make same as click from mouse?

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
   
   $( "#calTST" ).datepicker();
  
   $('#calTST').focus();
    
   $( "a:contains('13')" ).click();

 
  } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' >



<input type='text' id='calTST' name='calTST' >
```

*Note: The snippet is my test for `datepicker` and as i said it works on `chrome` and does not works on `firefox`*

Answer (score 0):

you can implement an event handler for select event like this

```
$("#calTST").datepicker({
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
 // code to run on selection
}});
```

Comment: I know this way but i want make everything from code as user doing by mouse, i don't want integrate like this

Comment: you can still do the `$('#calTST').focus();   $( "a:contains('13')" ).click();` part and the `onSelect` function will run when you fire the `click event`